# Source code is in JDK 1.4 and JUnit test cases in JDK 1.5

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am working on a project that is using JDK 1.4 and I am planning to write JUnit test cases in JDK 1.5 for several reasons like:

1. I wanna explore JDK 1.5
2. to use Mocking frameworks more efficiently.

Is it a good idea to do so??
(I've created two projects in Eclipse and am trying this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes go ahead. But you might not able to use few things for example generics. I mean if the original method is returing say, `Map`, you can't say in your test something like,

```
Map<String, Integer> map = someOriginalMehtod();
```

I suppose.

Comment: you can do that, will just get a some unchecked warnings

Answer (score 1):

No need for Java 5, as it seems James Carr backported Mockito to Java 4, see http://blog.james-carr.org/2009/10/01/using-mockito-with-junit3. I never used that backport personally though.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah is perfect. As long as you run it in Java 5 of course ;)

Java 1.4 is a subset of Java 1.5